# My own subversion repository and bugtracker

Tags: svn, bug-tracking

I am looking for software that I can download and install on a local server that will:

- Act as a subversion repository
- Have bug-tracking features
- Have web-interface similar to sites such as codeplex.com or bitbucket.org, etc.

Can you recommended any?

**Edit:**
Thanks for all the suggestions. It will take me some time to check them all.

Comment: Not Subversion but great: http://fossil-scm.org/

Comment: Trac has a good mix of wiki, bug tracker, and repo browser. http://trac.edgewall.org/

Answer (score 2):

I agree with eljunior on Trac with SVN.  It is a great combination that I use at home and work.  If you want to quickly try it out, Bitnami has a [Trac stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/trac) that you can download and have running in very little time.  You can also download Redmine and Mantis from Bitnami if you want to try them out.

As for Trac, some of the features that I use a lot are

- Wiki
- Repor Broswer - This is very nice because Trac will allow you to do things like link from tickets and the wiki to files within SVN
- Diff Viewer - Here is an [example](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/3966) of being able to link a diff view right in a ticket
- Tickets

There is also a desktop client that I have used a bit called [FatBug](http://fat-bug.com).  I am not affiliated with this piece of software but I thought I would mention.

If you do decide to go with Trac, I also use an image snipping tool called [Cropper](http://cropper.codeplex.com/) to upload images directly into Trac.  I am able to do this through a plug in I wrote.  If you want a copy, I will gladly send it to you.

Comment: I just want to mention that both the Trac and Redmine installers from BitNami also include Subversion. They also install all the dependencies required for running them like Apache, Python for Trac and Ruby for Redmine.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) ...which has support for multiple projects etc. wiki, tracker etc.

Comment: Redmine is RoR app, which brings some additional **big headache**

Comment: Not really if you are using Redmine via JVM (http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=63684)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) along with a Subversion installation.

HowtoForge has a tutorial for doing that in a Ubuntu server: http://www.howtoforge.com/subversion-trac-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: Does Trac expose the subversion repository in a similar manner to bitbucket?

Comment: yes, check it out the source code browser for the project Trac itself: http://trac.edgewall.org/browser

Comment: Trac is terrible pair for Subversion

Answer (score 0):

Subversion + WebSVN + (MantisBT|FlySpray|...)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever thought about JIRA which is commerical but why not. Runs in JVM / Tomcat etc. If you have less than 10 People you can buy it for a very low fee.